# Uncaught TypeError: document.getElementById(...).submit is not a function at HTMLDocument.<anonymous>

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I want to submit my form through jquery/javascript, to achieve this I'm using javascript (document.getElementById('formId').submit();  )
but we get Error:

> ```
>         file.php:144 Uncaught TypeError: document.getElementById(...).submit is not a function
>             at HTMLDocument.<anonymous> (file.php:144)
>             at fire (jquery.js:3048)
>             at Object.fireWith [as resolveWith] (jquery.js:3160)
>             at Function.ready (jquery.js:433)
>             at HTMLDocument.completed (jquery.js:104)
> ```

I found that if I'm using HTML tags in a form its give error 
HTML tag Like :

```
<ul class="pager">
  <li class="next" >
```

If I remove these tags in over form then it's working fine

```html
     <form action=""  name="formId" id="formId" method="post" >
              <fieldset  class='panel ques'  style='margin:5%;' id='ques_1' >
                Question &nbsp;1&nbsp;:: what is command for changing user information??</b><br /><br />
                <input type="radio" name="a" value="a" checked>
                <label for="55892169d2efc"> usermod</label><br /><br />
                <input type="radio" name="b" value="b">
                <label for="55892169d2f05"> useradd</label><br /><br />
                <input type="radio"  name="c" value="c">
                <label for="55892169d2f09"> useralter</label><br /><br />
                <input type="radio"  name="d" value="d">
                <label for="55892169d2f0c"> groupmod</label><br /><br />
                <ul class="pager">
                  <li class="next" >
                    <button type="text" style="float: right;" name="submit" class="btn btn-primary">
                      <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-lock" aria-hidden="true"></span>&nbsp;Finish
                    </button>
                  </li>
                </ul>
              </fieldset>
            </form>

    <script type="text/javascript">
                   document.getElementById('formId').submit();  
                 </script>
```

Answer (score 2):

You named your submit button `submit`, which is overriding the `submit()` method of the `form`. Renaming the button solves the issue.

So, as a general best practice, don't name or give things IDs that match object, property, or method names.

```html
<form action="http://example.com" name="formId" id="formId" method="post" >
              <fieldset  class='panel ques'  style='margin:5%;' id='ques_1' >
                Question &nbsp;1&nbsp;:: what is command for changing user information??<br><br>
                <input type="radio" name="a" value="a" checked>
                <label for="55892169d2efc"> usermod</label><br><br>
                <input type="radio" name="b" value="b">
                <label for="55892169d2f05"> useradd</label><br><br>
                <input type="radio"  name="c" value="c">
                <label for="55892169d2f09"> useralter</label><br><br>
                <input type="radio"  name="d" value="d">
                <label for="55892169d2f0c"> groupmod</label><br><br>
                <ul class="pager">
                  <li class="next" >
                    <button type="text" style="float: right;" name="btnSubmit" class="btn btn-primary">
                      <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-lock" aria-hidden="true"></span>&nbsp;Finish
                    </button>
                  </li>
                </ul>
              </fieldset>
            </form>

<script>
  document.getElementById('formId').submit();  
</script>
```